# Writing time every minute into text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to write the system time to a text file every minute. Every minute the batch script  should write to it in a new line. My current script is as follows:

```
`echo %time% > time.txt`.
```

I want it every minute continuous time flow in text file.

Comment: You used a tag for a windows batch file.  What OS are you using if you accepted the answer below?

Comment: windows  7 os..  .............................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to use >> instead of >

```
echo `date -u` >> time.txt
```

This will append times instead of over writting them.

If you want just the time you can use

```
echo `date +%k:%M:%S` >> time.txt
```

If you wanted this to happen every minute consider using a crontab. You can read more on crontabs [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

The following code will write out the time every 1 minute to a text file.

```
while(true) do
   sleep 60;
   echo `date +%k:%M:%S` >> time.txt
done;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

```
@echo off
setlocal

:loop
echo %time% >> time.txt
timeout /t 60
goto :loop
```

Comment: Solved my problem with HDD spin down which caused lags, thank you